# android edittext contextmenu

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contextmenu

In edittext long press created contextmenu. How to remove the contextmenu?
I tried this:

```
      et.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    et.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode,
                MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    });
```

But then I can not select text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can remove the menu altogether, but you can call menu.clear() in onPrepareActionMode and this will remove all the menu items from the menu. You'll have to remove the onLongClickListener in order to see the handles again as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class extending EditText and override the performLongClick() method, that should work as expected

```
class MyET extends EditText{

    public MyET(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performLongClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```